# Buying directly from smart contract at the the same block the liquidity is provided

Tags: etherscan, uniswap

I am trying out buying new listing from uniswap but bots always rally the price so high that it just doesn't make sense to enter until the market is fully cooled off.

I have found and application called Limitswap to buy when the price starts being available on uniswap BUT it does not purchase from the same block that liquidity got provided(most probably).

I am trying to understand if there is a way to buy coins before they are listed on uniswap and at the time when the liquidity is provided(meaning at the same block as liq. got provided) directly from the Etherscan Write contract tab or with python program. Any ideas would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I've examined the transaction history of many launches, and I found it quite common that many people bought in the same block in which liquidity was added. I tracked the logs and relative addressed and discovered something.

Basically, they use another smart contract to do the trade. Just at the launch time, within the same block, they would send hundreds of transaction to buy the token via their trade contract, and these transactions stuffed that block, some were before the liquidity and some were after. So finally the first one after the liquidity would succeed and all of the others would fail.

The problem is, how they got the exact launch time? I checked the history, all of these transactions were sent into the same block, which means the sender knew that liquidity was being added at that block, how could they know that? But if they don't know this, they should send lots of transactions during a certain period of time, that would cost way more gas fee and make this plan not profitable.

Comment: It's called miner exctrable value (MEV) and miners are selling their capacity to bot vendors.

Comment: Thx bruh! I thougth I would have to search for days to find out the underlying truth but it's right now here!